# Why can't I delete this cookie from the dev tools console?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have some cookies that control column layout in a grid.  They are set by the Javascript on the page and the server has/had nothing to do with them.  I'd like to clear them using a button in JS (reset to defaults).  Problem is they seem to be impossible to delete unless you use the browser GUI to do it.

I've read numerous posts, tried all of them, even https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie and its docCookies library.

Here is a transcript from the dev tools console, that shows just how tenacious these cookies are:

```
>document.cookie="food=hotdog"
 "food=hotdog"
>docCookies.keys()
 ["food", "ext-history-results", "ext-today-summaries", "csrftoken"]
>docCookies.removeItem("ext-history-results")
 true
>docCookies.keys()
 ["food", "ext-history-results", "ext-today-summaries", "csrftoken"]
>docCookies.removeItem("food")
 true
>docCookies.keys()
 ["ext-history-results", "ext-today-summaries", "csrftoken"]
>docCookies.removeItem("ext-history-results")
 true
>docCookies.keys()
 ["ext-history-results", "ext-today-summaries", "csrftoken"]
>document.cookie="food=hotdog"
 "food=hotdog"
>docCookies.keys()
 ["food", "ext-history-results", "ext-today-summaries", "csrftoken"]
>docCookies.removeItem("ext-history-results")
 true
>docCookies.keys()
 ["food", "ext-history-results", "ext-today-summaries", "csrftoken"]
>docCookies.removeItem("food")
 true
>docCookies.keys()
 ["ext-history-results", "ext-today-summaries", "csrftoken"]  //csrftoken is set by the server
>docCookies.removeItem("csrftoken")
 true
>docCookies.keys()
 ["ext-history-results", "ext-today-summaries", "csrftoken"]
>docCookies.removeItem("ext-today-summaries")
 true
>document.cookie          // output wrapped for "clarity"
"ext-history-results=o%3Acolumns%3Da%253Ao%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah9%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Aext-gen1133%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah1%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah2%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah3%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah4%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah5%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah6%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah7%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah8%5Esort%3Do%253Aproperty%253Ds%25253Agrouper%255Edirection%253Ds%25253AASC%255Eroot%253Ds%25253Adata; 
 ext-today-summaries=o%3Acolumns%3Da%253Ao%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah1%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah2%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah3%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah4%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah5%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah6%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah7%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah8%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah9%5Esort%3Do%253Aproperty%253Ds%25253ABox%255Edirection%253Ds%25253AASC%255Eroot%253Ds%25253Adata; 
 csrftoken=RMYlasyNxjPz8pMpn2gMvYxCscMQGX5W"
```

Why can't I delete these cookies?

And the docCookies code is below (it is on the link above as well, but in case that link changes)

```
/*\
|*|
|*|  :: cookies.js ::
|*|
|*|  A complete cookies reader/writer framework with full unicode support.
|*|
|*|  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie
|*|
|*|  This framework is released under the GNU Public License, version 3 or later.
|*|  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0-standalone.html
|*|
|*|  Syntaxes:
|*|
|*|  * docCookies.setItem(name, value[, end[, path[, domain[, secure]]]])
|*|  * docCookies.getItem(name)
|*|  * docCookies.removeItem(name[, path], domain)
|*|  * docCookies.hasItem(name)
|*|  * docCookies.keys()
|*|
\*/

var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },


  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + ( sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + ( sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: /* optional method: you can safely remove it! */ function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nIdx = 0; nIdx < aKeys.length; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the `ext-` cookies? Based on the name, I would assume those cookies to be managed by a browser extension and not the page itself.

Comment: ext- cookies are from extjs, the framework the page is authored in.  I'm trying to figure out how to clear them, so a customer can reset to defaults if they don't like the state their columns are in.

Comment: Does the RESET button do a post back to the server?  I'm assuming when it does, during the redrawing of the webpage, the control sets the cookie again.

Comment: Not wanting to round trip the server for a client side cookie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I posted this question, I saw this link on the right hand side of the page

[Why can't I delete this cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860/why-cant-i-delete-this-cookie?rq=1)

The first answer (from Andreas Peterson) had the answer:

```
docCookies.removeItem("ext-today-summaries", '/')
```

will remove the cookie.  The Path has to be specified, or it won't delete.